# how to give necessary permissions before installing the application in IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I use plugins such as geolocation, an alert appears with a confirmation window asking for authorization to use geolocation. I want to avoid this, and like some applications I would like to know what I can do so that, before installing the app, it will be shown the permissions that it must authorize in order for the app to work properly as the following image.

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not show the permission pop-up to user **before** installing the app. User must have to install the app and on launch only you can show such pop-up to user.

Other option,
Add your pop-up and permission related information/screenshot on **AppStore/PlayStore** so that before users install your app. They can read about permissions. No other option.

Comment: hey, can you help me please crack? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844347/my-map-works-but-at-some-point-of-the-navigation-of-my-app-appears-blank

Comment: can you help me please with this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894188/how-to-receive-a-push-notification-when-you-are-near-a-specific-place-using-a-ma

Answer (score 0):

you can't is **pop-up** on **PlayStore/AppStore**