# How to receive a push notification when you are near a specific place using a map?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm new to Ionic, and I'd like to know if you can give me some guidance. I am using Ionic 1. I have seen tutorials, and they use Google or one signal. But they are always basic tutorials and I have many doubts. I hope to do this for both iOS and Android.

My application has some coordinates in the database, I get them with a web service. I would like that when I'm near a place I get a push notification. I am currently using the Google Maps plugin `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` and the geolocation plugin `cordova-plugin-geolocation`.

- I would like you to give me advice or if you have had the experience of doing something like this.
- I also want to know if doing this has any cost.
- I am using Ionic 1 and the database is built in MySQL using PHP. I think the push notification is generated from the back-end?
- When I tap on the notification, can it contain an iconor redirect to a specific place in my app?

In conclusion:

What is the best alternative? I was thinking of some plugin that detects in the background when my location changes and when this happens (does the cordova-plugin-geolocation do it?) verify if I'm close to a certain place and send a local notification. For example, and when I tap on this notification I can get the id of that place and redirect to a place in my app.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Ionic 1 but the plugin you are going to want to use is [cordova-plugin-geofence](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geofence/). The link is the documentation for Ionic 3 and they show how to setup a geofence and show a notification when the user is within a certain radius of that area.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try [geofence](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geofence/)

[repo link](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence)

example links:

https://github.com/cowbell/ionic-geofence built with Ionic framework

https://github.com/tsubik/ionic2-geofence built with Ionic 2 framework

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geofence/ works on Ionic 1? I dont uderstand how to go to the determinate view of my app for example $state.go("state", { "id_Received":data })

Comment: did you try using the [ionic2's](https://github.com/tsubik/ionic2-geofence) example?

Comment: I have a problem with this, according to the documentation there is a limit to assign places.